# Execute .class files in Java

Tags: java

I'm planning to dynamically execute a .class files/bytecode. I'm trying to achieve this by first creating an unpacker which loads the .class files and jumps to the main function in the .class file and executes it while the unpacker shuts down.

How do I achieve this using Java?

Comment: try `java -classpath \{path}\MainClassName`

Comment: The issue with this is. I can't execute it directly. The class file will be encrypted. I want to decrypt it first and store the contents in a String or something of that kind. Then I technically want to run the contents of the String in memory. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: Not entirely sure whether this is what you're looking for, but the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html doc even contains a (dummy) example of a class loader that can load "arbitrary" class data - and this could also be loaded from memory (not a `String` - there you'll run into trouble with all the character set encoding cr4p - you should use a `byte[]` for binary data...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ZIP and if the classes (packages) are placed in its root, then it is not even needed to unpack it. You can use your archive directly:

```
java -classpath my.zip mypackage.MyClass
```

If you want to launch one Java code from another Java application, either use `Runtime.exec()`, which is simple but not quite reliable (you may need to know location of JRE or particular path in the system PATH), or, more reliable but also harder to implement, use class loader, let it load unpacked classes (you mentioned decryption, so classloader should also decrypt classes before loading them), select needed class via this class loader, then invoke the main method.

Comment: The issue with this is. I can't execute it directly. The class file will be encrypted. I want to decrypt it first and store the contents in a String or something of that kind. Then I technically want to run the contents of the String in memory. Is there a possibility to do that?

Comment: You realize that everyone who has access to the PC/VM/environment where your applications will be launched can copy your launcher and your encrypted code and thus get its unencrypted code. Do you really need encryption? I'd suggest you think of the Kerckhoffs's principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) that says: *A cryptosystem should be secure even if **everything** about the system, except the key, is public knowledge.*

Comment: Yes. That's fine with me!

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a single main class that calls other classes based on the arguments passed to it.